# Gradle error while adding MavenRepository configuration into a Custom Plugin: "Please specify which subtype of Authentication to create"

Tags: maven, authentication, gradle, artifactory, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add a maven convention to one of my plugins so that the user credentials can be discovered in a standardized way. When I add the credentials closure, I encounter the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'my.plugin']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'my.plugin']
   > Cannot create a Authentication named 'BasicAuthentication' because this container does not support creating elements by name alone. Please specify which subtype of Authentication to create. Known subtypes are: AwsImAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, DigestAuthentication, HttpHeaderAuthentication
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. The trick was to include the BasicAuthentication in the Plugin:

```
import org.gradle.authentication.http.BasicAuthentication;

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
```